# Copy a specific part of a string and addit to the start of each line based on a regex, pass on if not matched in Python2

Tags: python-2.7

I have a group of hashes that im looking to copy the **USERNAME** to the start of each line followed by a ':' symbol and rewrite over the file with the changes.

for example:

$krb5tgs$23$***USERNAME**$realm$test/spn*$12345

Would become:

**USERNAME:**$krb5tgs$23$***USERNAME**$realm$test/spn*$12345

The input will be given from a file. So far i have come up with this but as yet haven't got it working.

Any suggestions of the right way of doing this would be appreciated.

This regex works as expected so looking to incorporate that.

```
'\*(.*?)\$'
```

```
L=file.txt
file_object = open(L, 'a+')                                                                                          
while True:                                                                                                          
        lines = file_object.readline()                                                                               
        match = re.search(r'\*(.*?)\$', lines)                                                                        
        if match:                                                                                                     
                for line in fileinput.input([L], inplace=1):                                                          
                        sys.stdout.write('TEST'.format(l=lin))                                                        
        else:                                                                                                         
            pass                                                                                                      
        if not lines:                                                                                                 
            break                                                                                                    
file_object.close()
```

Second attempt: I can get every line to have "TEST:" at the start but cant quite get an ifstatement or similar working based on the match above.

```
with open(L, 'r') as f:                                                                                               
    lines = f.readlines()                                                                                            
lines = ['TEST:' + line for line in lines]                                                                            
with open(L, 'w') as f:                                                                                               
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Hi. What I've written above in the question is precisely accurate. I've used markup correctly to show this, (it took me a while to get it right).

Answer (score 0):

Usernames seem to be introduced by the sequence `$*`, and end at `$`. You should make that part of the regex. There are other things in the string that start with a `*`, so looking for that alone is probably not sufficient. I think `\$\*([^$]+)\$` might be better.

`re.search()` returns a match object, or `None`, so it's easy to see when to modify a line, and when to leave it alone.

Also, get into the habit of using context managers (`with` blocks) to work with files, instead of calling `.close()` manually.

```
username_re = re.compile(r'\$\*([^$]+)\$')

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = list(f)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        match = username_re.search(line)
        if match:
            line = match.group(1) + ':' + line
        f.write(line)
```

Writing to a different file for the output eliminates the risk of destroying input file if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you answer I'll give this a go and thanks for your advice on the regex parts.